# Express.js app frequently doesn't load new route without hard refresh?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm experiencing a strange issue. When I navigate from page to page in my Express.js app (currently I have three pages: Home, About, Contact), the page appears blank. Only when I do a hard refresh on my Mac (Shift Command R) do all of the assets load in. When I look at the Networks tab in Chrome Dev Tools, it appears as if the assets are loading in -- I don't see an 404's.

Here is a screenshot of my app directory for you to see what I'm working with:
http://d.pr/i/lQlV

Also, here is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
    , partials = require('express-partials')
    , app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('title', ' | ToDo App');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(partials());
});

app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    response.render('index', { title: "Home" + app.get('title') });
});

app.get('/home', function(request, response, next) {
    response.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/about', function(request, response) {
    response.render('about', { title: "About" + app.get('title') });
});

app.get('/contact', function(request, response) {
    response.render('contact', { title: "Contact" + app.get('title') });
});

app.use(function(request, response){
    response.render('404', { title: "404" + app.get('title') });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: That's so weird... everything looks good to me here. I suggest open the page using private mode or in different browser and try again.

Comment: Brian, did user568109's answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `app.router`, which handles all your routes:

```
app.use(app.router); 

app.get('/', function(req,res,next){
res.render('index');
});
```